# Uncaught InvalidValueError: initAutocomplete is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-api

I am trying to make an address box that has pickup/dropoff address. [Like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DERjI.png) With AngularJs.

Im using the  [Google Autocomplete API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete) so i can autocomplete as someone starts typing in the address.

addressBoxView.html :

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Pickup Address</label>
    <input type="input" class="form-control" id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter Address Here" ng-focus="initAutocomplete()">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Dropoff Address</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter Address Here">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

addressBoxDirective.js:

```
angular.module('app.directives.addressBox', [])
  .directive('addressBox', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        data: '='
      },
      templateUrl: 'shared/addressBox/addressboxview.html',
      controller: function($scope){

        $scope.initAutocomplete = function() {
          // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
          // location types.
          autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
              /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
              {types: ['geocode']});

          // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, run the fillinAddress function which will do something
          autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
        }

        function fillInAddress(){
          console.log(autocomplete);
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

---

First i get this error right away when the page runs/loads.

```
Uncaught InvalidValueError: initAutocomplete is not a function
```

Then when i focus on the pickup box i also get this error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Autocomplete' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.initAutocomplete (http://play.uvgrade.com:9000/shared/addressBox/addressBoxDirective.js:14:48)
    at fn (eval at <anonymous> (http://play.uvgrade.com:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14086:15), <anonymous>:4:239)
    at expensiveCheckFn (http://play.uvgrade.com:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15076:18)
    at callback (http://play.uvgrade.com:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:24546:17)
    at Scope.$eval (http://play.uvgrade.com:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16820:28)
    at Scope.$apply (http://play.uvgrade.com:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16920:25)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (http://play.uvgrade.com:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:24551:23)
    at HTMLInputElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (http://play.uvgrade.com:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4732:27)
    at HTMLInputElement.elemData.handle (http://play.uvgrade.com:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4544:28)
```

---

SOMETIMES, out of nowhere, it will start to work. But it will still give me an error like this on the console:

```
InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement
```

But most of the time it doesnt work. Am i not supposed to call the function using ng-focus? I tried putting the initAutocomplete functions around in different folders didnt make a difference.

Let me know if you have any questions, or you would like to see any more of my code. Please dont downgrade right away just ask and ill edit. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the Bootstrap-Angular way of doing,

```
$scope.getLocation = function(val) {
    return $http.get('//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
      params: {
        address: val,
        sensor: false
      }
    }).then(function(response){
      return response.data.results.map(function(item){
        return item.formatted_address;
      });
    });
  };
```